# How to Remove White Space above video Block

Tags: css

How to Remove White Space above video Block from Wordpress post.
[image]

Website URL- https://dooiz.com/babys-day-out-full-movie

Comment: Your theme is adding that space, you should contact their support.

Answer (score 1):

It's a styling related issue so you should be more than capable to fix this issue with CSS. This should be easily accessible through the following steps in your /wp-admin/ environment: Appearance > Customize.

Adding the following rule should solve your problem:

```css
.single article.has-embed {
   padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Optionally you can add a `!important` after the `0` in order to force the styling.